# Login control template and Control ID = Login

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

When using custom template for *Login control*, if we add control with  *ID = Login* and set its  *CommandName* to *“Login”*, then *Login control* will automatically handle authentication.

Control with *ID=Login* can be any control that supports event bubbling. 
Thus I assume this control can be either *Button, ImageButton, LinkButton* or any control that would contain *Button*, *ImageButton* or *LinkButton* and also be capable of transmitting Command event initially fired by one of the three containing Buttons?!

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like it can be any control that that causes event bubbling. See the page below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.layouttemplate(VS.80).aspx